# Is there a way to perform a GROUP BY from a list coming from a One-To-Many relationship in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, one-to-many

I have two tables,

tb_product

```
Id       typeProduct
1         Type1
2         Type1
3         Type1
```

Products 1,2 and 3 are equal due to typeProduct, but each product has linked attributes that differentiate them as well.

tb_product_attribute

```
idProduct   typeAttribute  valueAttribute
    1         Attr1         Value1 
    1         Attr2         Value3
    2         Attr1         Value1
    2         Attr2         Value3
    3         Attr1         Value2
    3         Attr3         Value3
```

Thus, products 1 and 2 would be due to attributes and values ​​of attributes, since 3 would be different because of the second attribute of it having the value different from the second attribute of the others.

The ideal result would be this, because I would know the details of the equality between them, but I do not know if this type of result would be possible.

```
total_rows  typeProduct   typeAttribute     valueAttribute
    2         Type1       Attr1, Attr2      Value1, Value3
    1         Type1       Attr1, Attr3      Value2, Value3
```

Comment: your question is not clear  (to me)   .. please update your question and add  the expected  result  .. or explain better your goal

Comment: How do you determine if a product is duplicated? Is idTipoProduto related to something? I assume that Product.Id is related to ProductAttributes.idProduto. Is this true?

Comment: With the sample data you provided, can you show us your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or without CTE

```
select  count(valueattribute) total_rows, 
        typeProduct, 
        typeAttribute, 
        valueAttribute 
from 
(select 
    (select top 1 tp.typeProduct 
        from tb_product as tp 
            where tp.Id = p.idProduct) as typeProduct,
    stuff((
        SELECT ', ' + [valueAttribute] 
        FROM tb_product_attribute 
        WHERE (idproduct = p.idproduct) 
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') AS valueAttribute,
    stuff((
        SELECT ', ' + [typeAttribute]
        FROM tb_product_attribute 
        WHERE (idproduct = p.idproduct) 
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') AS typeAttribute 
    from tb_product_attribute as p
        group by idproduct
) as subs
group by valueattribute, typeProduct, typeAttribute
```

Comment: The result of both posting returned what I needed, but its code ran faster. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group the attributes and values first then count each row

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT p.typeproduct,
       t.idproduct,
       STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + typeattribute
                FROM tb_product_attribute 
                WHERE idproduct = t.idproduct
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS typeattribute,
       STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + typevalue
                FROM tb_product_attribute 
               WHERE idproduct = t.idproduct
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS typevalue      
  FROM tb_product_attribute t
 INNER JOIN tb_product p
    ON t.idproduct = p.id
 GROUP BY p.typeproduct,
          t.idproduct
)

SELECT COUNT(*) total_rows,
       typeproduct,
       typeattribute,
       typevalue
  FROM cte
 GROUP BY typeproduct,
          typeattribute,
          typevalue
```

Result

```
total_rows  typeproduct typeattribute   typevalue
2           Type1       Attr1, Attr2    Value1, Value3
1           Type1       Attr1, Attr3    Value2, Value3
```

Comment: It worked very well. At first I used STUFF, but I did not get anywhere near that and my queries with 40k registrations took a long time, with that code, it only took 2 seconds with a total of 43492.
And with the ASpirin code, it ran faster still and presented the same results.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
create table tb_product  
  ( 
     id           INT 
     ,typeproduct CHAR(5) 
  ) 
create table tb_product_attribute  (
idProduct int,   typeAttribute char(5), valueAttribute char(6)
)
GO


CREATE Function dbo.TypeAttribute2Comma(@idProduct int)
returns varchar(max)
BEGIN
    declare @tmp varchar(max) 
    SET @tmp = '' 
    select @tmp = @tmp + typeAttribute + ', ' from tb_product_attribute where idProduct = @idProduct
    RETURN (select SUBSTRING(@tmp, 0, LEN(@tmp))) 

END 
GO

CREATE Function dbo.ValueAttribute2Comma(@idProduct int)
returns varchar(max)
BEGIN
    declare @tmp varchar(max) 
    SET @tmp = '' 
    select @tmp = @tmp + typeAttribute + ', ' from tb_product_attribute where idProduct = @idProduct
    RETURN (select SUBSTRING(@tmp, 0, LEN(@tmp))) 

END 
GO

INSERT tb_product 
       (id ,typeproduct) 
VALUES ( 1 ,'Type1'), 
       (2 ,'Type1'), 
       (3 ,'Type1') 

insert tb_product_attribute( idProduct   ,typeAttribute  ,valueAttribute) values
    (1, 'Attr1', 'Value1'), 
    (1, 'Attr2', 'Value3'),
    (2, 'Attr1', 'Value1'),
    (2, 'Attr2', 'Value3'),
    (3, 'Attr1', 'Value2'),
    (3, 'Attr3', 'Value3')

GO

select 
* 
,dbo.TypeAttribute2Comma(id) TypeAttribute2
,dbo.ValueAttribute2Comma(id) ValueAttribute2
from tb_product
```

Result

```
id          typeproduct TypeAttribute2 ValueAttribute2 
----------- ----------- -------------- ----------------
1           Type1       Attr1, Attr2   Attr1, Attr2
2           Type1       Attr1, Attr2   Attr1, Attr2
3           Type1       Attr1, Attr3   Attr1, Attr3
```